# How to create a stacked bar chart for Male/Female from a GroupBy node in KNIME?

Tags: dataframe, knime

I am working with KNIME and trying to create a stacked bar chart that shows the distribution of males and females across different departments in my company.

Here's a snapshot of my DataFrame after applying a GroupBy node:

insert screenshot here

I would like to transform this data into a stacked bar chart where each bar represents a department, and the bar is split into two sections (one for males, one for females) based on the count of each gender in the department.

However, I am not sure how to achieve this in KNIME. I cannot find suitable options in the "Bar Chart" node. Could someone provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

KNIME 4.7.3

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I tried changing the way I grouped the DataFrame, I also tried coloring the 'Male' and 'Female' elements.

I attempted to create a new column by concatenating 'Service' and 'Sex',

but nothing worked...

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the KNIME hub which shows you how to do this.

See [https://hub.knime.com/-/spaces/-/latest/~6OgSVMxibsZQNMKT/](https://hub.knime.com/-/spaces/-/latest/%7E6OgSVMxibsZQNMKT/) for the example